# Im trying to make a code where a person will bet on a number which is randomly generated b/w 1, 6 but even if i get it correct the it says that I lost

Tags: python, discord.py

Im trying to make a code where a person will bet on a number which is randomly generated b/w 1, 6 but even if i get it correct the it says that I lost

```
#importing the needs
import discord
import random
from discord.ext import commands

client = discord.Client()

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix='%')


r = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]

@client.event

async def on_ready():
  print('we are ready')

@client.command()

#getting the input from the user
async def play(ctx, a):
  await ctx.send('Type the number you bet on ')
  r = random.randint(1, 2)

  #checking if the input is equal to the randomly generated number
  #Here is where the problem is
  if a == r:
    await ctx.send('you won ' + str(r) + ' you chose ' + str(a))
  else:
    await ctx.send('you lost ' + str(r) + ' you chose ' + str(a))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is likely because the value received and the random integer are of different types.

Try type casting like follows:

```
if int(a) == r:
    ...
```